# What to do when no export is needed in TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I had a problem while making some demo files using TypeScript, each file is considered to run alone (no import or export needed).

The problem is that the files leaked to each other as they all went global (I'll appreciate if someone explains why this happened). I found a few ways to get rid of this as wrapping them in a module or a namespace, or even exporting an empty object.

What I need to know is the best practice that should be done in this situation? which solutions is considered the best? especially that I thought I can face the same situation if I have multiple files that are required for their side-effects only or something.

Comment: Please provide the code of the two files, and ideally also what leaked for you. We can't guess what variables you leaked globally and how without some code.

Comment: So are all these typescript files being imported into a single html file? Best practice would be to make unique names for functions that are in the same scope, but its hard to tell without knowing how your file structure is

Comment: Actually they're just refactoring demos running with node, no html files or so. That's why I thought it's not so important to give a sample of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had a problem while making some demo files using TypeScript
>
> What I need to know is the best practice that should be done in this situation? which solutions is considered the best? especially that I thought I can face the same situation if I have multiple files that are required for their side-effects only or something.

The only time I've experienced it in my long career as well is with demo files. I had this when creating TypeScript deep dive so I would put in some junk at the top of the file e.g. [see const](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/e677f6ddb86c76849688ca276126cfb7fcf1bb2d/code/es6/const.ts)

```
export var asdfasdfasfadf = 123;
```

## Why its not a concern

You do not see it happening in real world code because you start you brain with *module* mind set. E.g.

- In a file with zero dependencies you are normally thinking : What am I going to export
- In a file where you are going to action something you are normally thinking: What will I need to import. As simple as `import fs from 'fs'` makes it a module

Comment: I think this is a very logical solution, thank you very much.
By the way, I'm a huge fan of your book ❤️